# Simple Twitch status

Tags: javascript, jquery, stream, status, twitch

I am looking for Twitch status toggle for my forum. I have a list with streamers and I want green/red point for online/offline streams or just ONLINE or OFFLINE. I found what I need but was unable to make it work. Every help will be welcome. I dont have any javascript knowledge, so please dont blame me for stupid mistakes.

Here is the code I found:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.ltwitch').each(function () {
        var tnick = $(this).data('tnick');
        var span = $(this).next();
     $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+tnick+".json?callback=?", function(c) {
      if (c.stream == null) {
       span.html("Offline");
      } else {
       span.html("Online");
      }
     });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="ltwitch" href="#" data-tnick="alohadancetv">Aloha</a> (<span>...</span>)
```

```
http://jsfiddle.net/LYv3R/5/
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the request **with** your `client_id`

Example:  `?client_id=48728413r2fdmq4i4otfjrtu9f8z2ou`

You can Register an application and receive a `client_id` [here](https://www.twitch.tv/settings/connections) *(at the bottom of the page)*

In your code *(this will only work if you use your own client id ofc)*:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.ltwitch').each(function () {
        var tnick = $(this).data('tnick');
        var span = $(this).next();
        $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+tnick+"?client_id=48728413r2fdmq4i4otfjrtu9f8z2ou", function(c) {
            if (c.stream == null) {
                span.html("Offline");
            } else {
                span.html("Online");
            }
        });
    });
});
```